# Book about the Second Coming

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in 1998, a sci-fi book about the Second Coming of Jesus. I cannot remember the name of it, nor the author. The plot is that the military had this machine that would help a man become as if he was Jesus. This man came into America and started performing miracles. People around the world started coming to see him, but a few groups did not believe he was Jesus and decided to send assassins to kill him. The main character of the book is a reporter who unfolds the truth and wanted to save him. Has anybody by chance read this book?

It was a bestseller soft paperback when I read it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it might be [Left Behind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_Behind) series by Tim LaHaye and Jerry B. Jenkins.

Some of what you describe sounds like the book's description, from Wikipedia:

> Left Behind is a series of 16 best-selling novels by Tim LaHaye and Jerry B. Jenkins, dealing with Christian dispensationalist End Times: the pretribulation, premillennial, Christian eschatological viewpoint of the end of the world. The primary conflict of the series is the members of the Tribulation Force against the Global Community and its leader Nicolae Carpathia—the Antichrist.

The story itself is partly focussed around a journalist called "Buck" Williams, which might be where you're remembering that from.

The main discrepancy between what you seem to remember and this series is the military's machine to make someone like Jesus, which these books don't have. Other than that, it's pretty similar.

Comment: thanks 4 your answer i will look into those novels to see if that is the 1 am looking for..thanks again

Comment: Matt I looked up the books from the left behind series but is non is the 1 I been looking for..I know that the info I gave is not much to go on..I don't know what else to do or where to look to find this book..

Comment: Fair enough, shame it wasn't, I hope that you find the ones you're looking for =)

Answer (score 1):

It could be [The Last Day](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1813844.The_Last_Day) by Glenn Kleier

A military installation is mysteriously destroyed and a person emerges from the wreckage.
The person who is Female then appears in Israel and proclaims a new Gospel. She calls herself Jeza,

The novel also features a tv reporter follows Jeza around and is determined to find out the truth,